# Native C++ performance using C# or within C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, native-code

I was wondering if the two following scenarios have the same performance impact on native C++ code (if there is any performance impact at all).

Let's assume I have the function `cpp_calc()` that is doing some calculation stuff and is written in native C++. Also, there is `cs_show_gui_stuff()`, which is written in C#.

Now, which of the following scenarios will worsen the native c++ performance (if there is any performance penalty at all)?

1. **Creating a .Net (C#) application** that runs `cs_show_gui_stuff()` and calls `cpp_calc()` in the native C++ dll using `DllImport` or turning C++ into a COM DLL.
2. **Creating a C++ application** that implements `cpp_calc()` in C++ and runs `cs_show_guid_stuff()` by placing the C# code in a .Net COM DLL.

Thanks :-)

Comment: this question is somewhat a little bit related to performance of native code. hope it helps, though not answering yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693477/ccli-does-the-native-parts-written-in-pure-c-but-compiled-in-cli-are-as-fast

Comment: Before trying to figure that out, did you actually test that the calculation function does not have acceptable performance in C#? Premature optimization yadda yadda... you all know the text :)=

Comment: @Medo42 - Its more of a theoretical question.
I sometimes find myself having that question in mind in various scenarios. If someone can give a complete answer to that question we won't need to test (in simple cases).And besides that, we will all learn something :-) .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It really depends on what the other parts of the system are mainly written in. From a performance-only perspective, one `PInvoke` (via `DllImport` attribute) call will probably be faster than one COM call if the method arguments do not need any special marshaling.

A third, and probably the best alternative, is to create a managed C++/CLI library that calls the unmanaged C++ method with nearly no performance impact and add a reference to the C++/CLI library in the C# application. The C# application can then make managed method calls to the C++/CLI application, which in turn can make unmanaged method calls. While this adds one level of indirection, it will provide way better performance than the methods you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Either way You are going to bump on Just-In-Time compiler. I guess the penalty is the same on both scenarios. I would personally choose the first one, because .NET libs are more robust on the GUI - WPF, Silverlight, WinForms, WebForms, Razor ... You see what I mean.