# A Few questions about CLI (C++ .NET?)

Tags: string, c++-cli

So ive got a few questions about CLI
In visual studio it called CLR..

My **First Question**, what is the XOR Sign? (^), I know that it a bitwise operator
But when im doing let's say

```
int ^ A = 5;
int B = 5;

Console::WriteLine(A->ToString());
Console::WriteLine(B.ToString());
```

What are the diffrences beetwen those 2? It's like pointers in C?

**Question 2:**

```
MyClass ^ MC1 = gcnew MyClass(); //What is the advantage of using gcnew?
MyClass MC2 = new MyClass(); //Why 'new' keyword dosent work on CLI? or maybe there is another way of using it?
```

**Question 3:**

```
Int32 B(int i)
{
    return i;
}
Int32 ^ C(int ^ i)
{
    return i;
}
```

What is the diffrence beetwen returnning ^ Variable and Normal Variable?

**Question 4:**

```
void StringFunc1(String ^ S)
{
    Console::WriteLine(S);
}
void StringFunc2(String S)
{
    Console::WriteLine(S); //Why a normal string dosent work?
}
Console::WriteLine("Hello World");
Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
```

What are the diffrences beetwen L"Hello World" and "Hello World"? What's the 'L' For? Why a normal string dosent work on '*StringFunc2*'?

**Question 5:**

```
MyClass ^ MC1 = gcnew MyClass();
MyClass ^ MC2 = gcnew MyClass();
int i[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int ii[,] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }; //How do i write dimensional array?
String s[] = { "Hey", "Dude" }; //Why string array dosent work?
MyClass MCArray[] = { MC1, MC2 }; //Why MyClass array dont work?
```

Comment: please remove `C` tag.

Comment: Q2 [Why "gcnew" instead of just plain "new"? - MSDN Blogs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hsutter/archive/2003/12/05/53522.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

> My First Question, what is the XOR Sign? (^), I know that it a bitwise operator But when im doing let's say
>
> ```
> int ^ A = 5;
> int B = 5;
>
> Console::WriteLine(A->ToString());
> Console::WriteLine(B.ToString());
> ```
>
> What are the diffrences beetwen those 2? It's like pointers in C?

The ^ is used for managed references, which are like pointers but refer to objects stored on the managed heap. For [value types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) line **int**, you don't need to use a reference, but if you do, the object is [boxed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).

> Question 2:
>
> ```
> MyClass ^ MC1 = gcnew MyClass(); //What is the advantage of using gcnew?
> MyClass MC2 = new MyClass(); //Why 'new' keyword dosent work on CLI? or maybe there is another way of using it?
> ```

gcnew is the equivalent of "new" for managed types. gcnew only works for managed types and "new" only works for unmanaged types.

> Question 3:
>
> ```
> Int32 B(int i)
> {
>     return i;
> }
> Int32 ^ C(int ^ i)
> {
>     return i;
> }
> ```
>
> What is the diffrence beetwen returnning ^ Variable and Normal Variable?

Same as in question #1. The first function returns the object in value type form, the second one returns a boxed Int32.

> Question 4:
>
> ```
> void StringFunc1(String ^ S)
> {
>     Console::WriteLine(S);
> }
> void StringFunc2(String S)
> {
>     Console::WriteLine(S); //Why a normal string dosent work?
> }
> Console::WriteLine("Hello World");
> Console::WriteLine(L"Hello World");
> ```
>
> What are the diffrences beetwen L"Hello World" and "Hello World"? What's the 'L' For? Why a normal string dosent work on 'StringFunc2'?

Normally the L prefix is used for wide-character (wchar_t) strings, but for managed string literals you don't need it. The compiler will recognize that it is being used where a System::String is expected, and will just create a System::String instead of a raw character array.

Also you need the hat (^) because System::String is a reference type, and you can't unbox [reference types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/490f96s2(v=vs.80).aspx).

> Question 5:
>
> ```
> MyClass ^ MC1 = gcnew MyClass();
> MyClass ^ MC2 = gcnew MyClass();
> int i[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
> int ii[,] = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }; //How do i write dimensional array?
> String s[] = { "Hey", "Dude" }; //Why string array dosent work?
> MyClass MCArray[] = { MC1, MC2 }; //Why MyClass array dont work?
> ```

The [] syntax doesn't work for managed types. You need to use the **array** keyword:

```
array<int>^ i = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

To create a multi-dimentional array:

```
array<int, 2>^ ii = { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } };
```

To create an array of strings:

```
array<String^>^ s = { "a", "b" };
```

To create an array reference types:

```
array<MyClass^>^ mc = { gcnew MyClass(), gcnew MyClass() };
```

Comment: Thanks so much, i appriciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The operator ^ is the managed equivalent of a pointer in C++. It's called a Handle to a reference type.The gcnew allocate an instance of a type which will be garbage collected when it will become inaccessible.
The L"Hello World" means that hello world will be a whar_t literal 
If you want a array you can declare it like that
`array<int>^ myArray= gcnew array<int>(x);
 for(int i=0; i<x; i++)
     myArray[i] = i;`

If you want a two dimensional array you go like that
 `array<String^,2>^ myStringBiDimensionalArray = gcnew array<String^,2>(4,2);
        myStringBiDimensionalArray [0,0] = "Something";
        myStringBiDimensionalArray [1,0] = "Something else";
        myStringBiDimensionalArray [2,0] = "42";
        myStringBiDimensionalArray [3,0] = "Why not zoidberg";`

Comment: Thanks so much, i appriciate your help.
By the way, does CLI Is really a .NET?
Or it's a C++ Native like Win32?

Comment: I think this post will help you more than I will, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693477/ccli-are-native-parts-written-in-pure-c-but-compiled-in-cli-as-fast-as-pure.