# What is the difference between C++/CLI and C#/VB with unsafe and extern?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, c++-cli, unsafe

.NET has C# and VB* as (relatively) high-level languages, both of which compile to the .NET CLI intermediate code (.NET's equivalent of Java's "bytecode"), and not to native machine code. There is also C++/CLI, which lets you write code for the .NET CLI intermediate code.

These can be familiar with each other the same way C#/VB projects can, with C++/CLI code able to use C#-defined elements (classes, methods, properties) with keywords like `gcnew` and notation `^`, and C#/VB code. C++/CLI allows working with pointers, memory allocation, and getting and setting the actual bytes in memory (by pointers). However, these are things that can be done with C# (and VB?) with the `unsafe` keyword.

Is there a difference between the two ways? Are there things you can achieve with one but not the other? Is there a performance difference (consider both compile to intermediate .NET CLI code and not machine code)?

* when I say C#/VB, I only know the C# part so I may by wrong. I'm not familiar with VB.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: minor note: most things that you can do in C# with the `unsafe` keyword, you can also now do *without* the `unsafe` keyword via spans and ref-returns/locals - in many cases, with the JIT still eliding any bounds checks (if the JIT is sure from the context that you aren't exceeding it)

Comment: Should not have `c++` tag, since C++/CLI is not C++.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason for C++/CLI is to have an easy way to interface to native c++ libraries, this is the most important difference.

In c++/cli there is a possibility to compile native code using the native VS C++ compiler. This can provide a speedup since it is possible to use lower level techniques, including SIMD, and since the compiler in general is better at optimization.[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5693477/ccli-are-native-parts-written-in-pure-c-but-compiled-in-cli-as-fast-as-pure).

If both compile to MSIL your performance will in both cases mostly depend on the JIT compiler. But there might be some minor difference I'm not aware of.